# Inputted integer to char array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, type-conversion, nested-loops

So I recently attempted to do the HackerRank challenge that involved counting a number's holes and adding them up, and after a bit of research, I ended up making it into a char array and choosing three values to increment and add up to the sum as shown below:

```
 public static int countHoles(int num) {

    //create integers that count how many a number with no, one or two holes shows up
    Integer noHoles = 0;
    Integer oneHole = 0; 
    Integer twoHoles = 0; 
    Integer sum = 0;
    Integer length = 0;

    //turn the inputted number into a char array
    char [] digits = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
    System.out.println(digits);
    length = digits.length;

    //These nested loops incremement the numbers initialized above as the first for-each loop goes through each index value of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
        if (digits[i]== 1 || digits[i]==2 || digits[i]==3 || digits[i]==5 || digits[i]==7){
            noHoles++;
        } else if (digits[i]==4 || digits[i]==6 || digits[i]==9 || digits[i]==0){
            oneHole+= 1;
        } else if (digits[i]==8){
            twoHoles+= 2;
        }

    }
    //add up the incremented integers. twoHoles is doubled as each unit counts as two holes and noHoles is 0 regardless of its values
    sum = oneHole + twoHoles;
    return sum;
    }
}
```

but the char array always return as a normal integer! I can't try the modulus approach since 0 is used (has one hole in it), and a bunch of variants on String.valueOf(num).toCharArray() such as ("" + num).toCharArray() and Integer.toString(number).toCharArray(), but it stills outputs the inputted number instead of the wanted char array. Of course, the rest of the method spits out 0 because of the empty array too.

I'm a bit of a newbie, but damn is this frustrating. I feel like it's a micro-detail I haven't seen or don't know instead of my logic. Any help please?

Comment: What did you want the output to be? (Also use `Arrays.toString` when printing `Array`'s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a `char` to an `int` with the incorrect `int` values (for example, `'1' != 1`). It would safer to compare `char` to `char`:

```
if (digits[i] == '1' || digits[i] == '2' || digits[i] == '3' || digits[i] == '5' || digits[i] == '7') {
    noHoles++;
} else if (digits[i] == '4' || digits[i] == '6' || digits[i] == '9' || digits[i] == '0') {
    oneHole += 1;
} else if (digits[i] == '8') {
    twoHoles += 2;
}
```

You also don't need the `noHoles` variable, as it goes unused after it's incremented. If you remove `noHoles`, you can also remove the first if-statement where you check if the number is `1`, `2`, etc.

Also to print your `char[]`, use `Arrays#toString`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was a small detail I missed! And I was going to use noHoles to print out how many numbers don't have holes, which worked out just fine. Thanks again! Is there a reason why you recommended I'd print it out with Arrays#toString? I've never seen that before, and it still worked fine without it.

Comment: @T.Bifo Well `Arrays#toString` is what you use to print arrays. `System.out.println` worked fine for you in this scenario because there's an overloaded method that accepts a `char[]`. You won't be so lucky when working with arrays of a different type!

Comment: Oh I see so it's a tip for proper coding! I'll keep that in mind in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you must add some quotes to your test since digits[i] is a char, you can not compare them this way. `digits[i]== '1'` works.
For instance :

```
    char five = '5';
    if (five == 5) {
        System.out.println("They are similar");
    } else {
        System.out.println("They are not similar");
    }
```

print not similar.

Second, `System.out.println(digits)` results in a call to `print(char[] s)` then `println()`, and if you check the javadoc of `print(char[] s)`, it says :

> Print an array of characters. The characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

So it performs a byte-by-byte print out. So its normal that it prints an integer.